# indexing input ID issue in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have 2 input values to execute t.test in my shiny application. But when i tried below code, the output is not displayed. Can anyone help me

```
output$renderprint <- renderPrint({
    t.test(paste0(input$num ,"~" ,input$cat,data = input_data))    
})
```

`input$num` is numeric values and `input$cat`is character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example of a shiny app showing the results of a t test.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    textOutput("mytextoutput")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    output$mytextoutput <- renderPrint({

        t.test(sleep$extra ~ sleep$group, data = sleep)

    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including some example data and an app we can run, we can provide a more detailed answer.